# Alterar dados de uma coluna na tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Preciso alterar 1200 registros somente de uma coluna na tabela, gerei os dados no generatedata, o restante das colunas devem permanecer com os dados, alguém sabe um jeito rápido para este processo?

Comment: Use o update com uma cláusula where cujo id é maior que tanto e menor que tanto

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes você pode me ajudar dando um exemplo prático?

Comment: O @GuilhermeLopes quis dizer para você fazer um update dentro do intervalo de id onde os 1200 registros se encontram. Exemplo seria algo assim: `update tabela set coluna = newValor where id > 1 and id <=1200`, levando em consideração que os 1200 registros são sequenciais.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Obrigado pela resposta, os id's não são sequenciais :/

Comment: O que difere esses 1200 registros dos demais? Se não tive algo pra filtrá-los, não tem como fazer de forma automática.

Comment: Se vc der uma amostra dos dados, da estrutura da tabela e do resultado que pretende fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: como o diegofm disse, se não tiver algo para filtrá-los, ou seja, uma string identificando aqueles 1200 registros, por exemplo:

`id`, `nome`, `exemplo`, `special`

Ai na coluna special, teria por exemplo um int que ao fazer a pesquisa pelos 1200 registros, eles teriam um numero 1 no special, e o resto não, assim não seriam afetados

Comment: Consegue fazer uma consulta que resulta somente nos registros que precisa ?

Answer (score 1):

Aonde eu trabalho já tive situações como estas e resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
BEGIN
  --cursor com o select dos dados que irei realizar o update 
  for c_prod in (select a.id, a.produto FROM produtos a WHERE a.id IN (1, 
  23, 45, 46, 47, 49, 55 ...));
  LOOP
      --inserir todos os dados do cursor em uma tabela auxiliar
      INSERT INTO produtos_temp VALUES (c_prod.id, c_prod.produto);

  end loop;
      --executando o update desejado
      UPDATE produtos a SET a.status = 'atualizado' 
       SELECT b.* FROM produtos_temp b
       WHERE a.id = b.id;
END;
```

Dessa forma você captura os dados que quer atualizar dentro de um cursor, em seguinda no loop implicito você insere os dados do id recuperado na tabela auxiliar assim poderá manter uma especie de backup dos mesmo, e por fim executa o update dos dados cujo id constem nessa tabela auxiliar.
Lembrando que para isso é necessário um pouco de conhecimento em PL/SQL.